# How can I access the second element with the same attributes using Watir?

Tags: internet-explorer, attributes, watir

I have a page with HTML like this:

```
<a href="1">reply</a>
<a href="2">reply</a>
```

I need to get value of href attribute for the second link.

I can not use `:text`, because it will return `href` attribute for the first link.

```
browser.link(:text, "reply").href
=> "{site}1"
```

I can use `:index`, but if anything on that page changes, it could break.

```
browser.link(:index, 2).href
=> "{site}2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browser.link(:text => "reply", :index => 1).href
=> "{site}2"
```

Sources:

- http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Multiple+Attributes
- http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/How+and+What
- http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Ways+Available+To+Identify+HTML+Tag
- http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Methods+Supported+by+Element
- http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/wtr-general/2006-November/008001.html
- http://zeljkofilipin.com/2007/02/06/watir-select-element-using-multiple-attributes/

Comment: This answer is now a little out-of-date because watir and watir-webdriver now use zero-based indexing, meaning that the :index value for this example should be 1. ...Or am I smoking something?